# Count Occurrences of Reserved Characters in Regexp (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, reserved-words

I am trying to count the occurrences of normally reserved characters in Regexp in a given string. So for example, the asterisk (*) is a reserved character in Regexp. So, while I can do this:

```
var textareaId = document.getElementById("textareaId").value;
var occ = (textareaId.match(/i/g) || []).length;
alert(occ);
```

I can't do this:

```
var textareaId = document.getElementById("textareaId").value;
var occ = (textareaId.match(/*/g) || []).length;
alert(occ);
```

I tried using the unicode equivalent of an asterisk (\u002A), escaping the asterisk, using a Regexp constructor, and putting the asterisk in an array, but it dosen't seem to match. It always gives this error when I put it directly in the variable occ:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

This also applies to all other reserved characters in regexp (brackets, parenthesis, carrots, etc.).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to escape it: `/\*/g`! The `*` is always preceded by something if not then it must be litteral `*` which need to be escaped, otherwise it will cause problems (considered as a comment start in your case)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape the asterisk with a backslash (`\`).

Here is an exampel:

```js
str = 'alskjdfalk*sdjf alksdjf* aljsdf01830*912838123*'
var occ = (str.match(/\*/g) || []).length;
console.log(occ);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Dekel's answer is the correct way to search for a reserved character using regex. You can also just avoid regex and split on the reserved character and take the `length` minus 1:

```js
var str = 'alskjdfalk*sdjf alksdjf* aljsdf01830*912838123*'
var count = str.split('*').length - 1;
console.log(count);
```